# Shared global state in a qt5 python 3.6 program

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables, opc-ua

I am attempting to use a module named "global_data" to save global state information without success. The code is getting large already, so I`ll try to post only the bare essentials.

```
from view import cube_control
from ioserver.ioserver import IOServer
from manager import config_manager, global_data
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #sets up initial data
    config_manager.init_manager()
    #modifies data
    io = IOServer()
    #verify global data modified from IOServer.__init__
    global_data.test() #success
    #start pyqt GUI
    cube_control.start_view()
```

So far so good. However in the last line cube_control.start_view() it enters this code:

```
#inside cube_control.py
def start_view():
    #verify global data modified from IOServer.__init__
    global_data.test() #fail ?!?!
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Running the **global_data.test() in this case fails**. printing the entire global state reveals it now somehow reverted back to the data setup by config_manager.init_manager()

How is this possible?

While Qt is running I have a scheduler called every 10 seconds, also reporting a failed test.

However once the Qt GUI is stopped (clicked "x"), and I run the test from console, it succeeds again.

Inside the global_data module I`ve attempted to store the data in a dict inside both a simple python object as well as a ZODB in memory database:

```
#inside global_data
state = {
    "units" : {}
}
db = ZODB.DB(None) #creates an in memory db
def test(identity="no-id"):
    con = db.open()
    r = con.root()
    print("test online: ", r["units"]["local-test"]["online"], identity)
    con.close()
```

Both have the exact same problem. Above the test is only done using the db.

The reason I attempted to use a db is that I understand threads can create a completely new global dictionary. However the 2 first tests are in the same thread. The cyclic one is in its own thread and could potentially create such a problem...?

### File organization

If it helps my program is organized with the following structure:

[image]

There is also a "view" folder with some qt5 GUI files.

The IOServer attempts to connect to a bunch of OPC-UA servers using the opcua module. No threads are manually started there, although I suppose the opcua module does to stay connected.

### global_data id()

I attempted to also print(id(global_data)) together with the tests and found that the ID is the same in IOServer AND top level code, but **changes inside the cube_control.py#start_view**. Should not these always refer to the same module?

Answer (score 0):

I`m still not sure what exactly happened. But apparently this was solved by removing the **init**.py file inside of the folder named manager. Now all imports of the module named "global_data" points to the same ID.

How using a **init**.py file caused a second instance of the same module remains a mystery